# How are multiple page views created in a game?

Tags: c++, xna, directx

Many game examples/tutorials focus only on the rendering of the main game and don't show the rest of the game, like the first landing page, splash screen, high scores page, credits page and so on.

For something like DirectX and XNA, how are these other screens created/rendered?

Comment: ...The same way the rest of the game is rendered?

Comment: If what you mean is you want to have multiple screens, you should look into a `screenmanager`. It basically keeps track of screens and can add/remove them and so makes it easy to create menus, start screens, etc. I think Microsoft had a sample that was very easy to work with, but I'm not sure if they still have it.

Comment: Thanks for that tip, with that keyword I was able to find this example from Microsoft where they build an XNA game that uses multiple screens. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsphonetrainingcourse_multitouchgamedevelopmentwithxna_topic2.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to the Microsoft sample mentioned by Davidsbro, if you wanted to create your own  basic game state management system you could do so through the use of an enum switch. For this approach you would declare an enum type and set it's default value, in this case the default value could be the main menu of a  game. In XNA this would look something like the following:

```
enum GameScene { menu, game };
GameScene scene = GameScene.menu;
```

Inside of the games update method you would then implement a switch statement which would be responsible for handling both enum states:

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    switch (scene)
    {
            case GameScene.menu:
            {
                // Perform menu scene logic
                break;
            }
            case GameScene.game:
            {
                // Perform game scene logic
                break;
            }
    }

    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

You would then need to implement another switch within the draw method similarly to the enum switch above.

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

    switch (scene)
    {
        case GameScene.menu:
            {
                // Draw menu scene
                break;
            }
        case GameScene.game:
            {
                // Draw game scene
                break;
            }
    }

    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

Additionally you would need to implement some form of logic to transition between the different game states. This could be achieved through user input or some form of game timer.